# asp.net 5 preview templates - web site

Tags: asp.net, templates

Very new to visual studio and have been working through tutorials.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992208/Angular-JS-Application-with-MVC-Web-API-ASPNET-and

When starting a new project it says to select the asp.net 5 preview template web site but I only have the options Empty, Web API, and Web Application.

Would I chose Web Application or do I need to download the template "web site"?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Yes I'm usiang VS2015

Comment: make a screenshot of your "New ASP.NET Project" window

Answer (score 0):

File, New Project. Don't do File New Website.

Make sure in the version drop down in the top left you have .NET 4.5 or later selected. For a new project, probably best to go with the latest.

If you still don't see the ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates, you may need to reinstall VS 2015.

Comment: Using .NET 4.6.  Still don't see the web site template but thanks will try to reinstall.

Comment: Pay careful attention when you do. I can't remember if there is a web specific setting. You may actually be able to just run the installer and add additional components without needing to uninstall.